# How to crop(Resize) capture image from iPhone and selecting from photo album?

Tags: iphone, ios, resize, camera, crop

i have created custom camera overlay view from this blog [AROVerlayViewController](http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297) it's all working properly but i have one problem after capturing image the image is going to be streched while showing in ImageView[image: first custom camera image]
[image: image view that changed in re-size mode] here as you can see the image is going to be stretched it's not showing the original captured image. and how to add location while capturing image. for image cropping i have used this code [from here](https://devforums.apple.com/message/2437#2437)

Comment: How are you getting the image selected by the picker? Or are you just using the currently visible area of the screen?

Comment: @lostInTransit thnx 4 rply.but sorry i have get image selection from (Album)picker perfectly check new question.

Comment: @lostInTransit can anybody help me.all users

Comment: sorry but I am not really sure what the question is. Are you trying to resize the image that the camera captures and returns or the image you created from the current screen view?

Comment: @lostInTransit could you plz check out the instagram and picyou application. there they have created custom camera.

Comment: @Hrushikesh  bro...I need your help,are you there ??

Comment: man I need your help...I want to make a custom cam like this

I have made a camera overlay like this..but  how to get a cropped size

Comment: And in your second screen shot..you are giving effects exactly like instagram manner,How to do that..now I am moving the selected photo to another view and user can pick the effects from an actionsheet

Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have solved my problem by this example it's very useful.
https://github.com/Nyx0uf/NYXImagesKit

Answer (score 1):

So it is the camera with which you are taking a picture right (even if its a camera with custom overlay views). Then to get the high res image, you will need to get the actual image (not edited) when your app hits the UIImagePickerControllerDelegate method.

Specifically in this method

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
```

The dictionary **info** has a value with key **UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage** which is what you are looking for.

Comment: i can't access this method i have created `AVCaptureSesstion` and i am stilling image from this code `-(void)btnCapture:(id)sender
{
    [[self captureManager] captureStillImage];
    [[captureManager captureSession] stopRunning];
    UIImage *image = [[self captureManager] stillImage];
//    image=[image scaleProportionalToSize:CGSizeMake(310, 390)];
    open.image = image;
    [open.imageView setImage:[[self captureManager] stillImage]];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:open animated:YES];
}`